# Bernoulli mixture models for image classification, pathological cases

Tags: machine-learning, pca, mixture-distribution

I'm trying to use a Bernoulli mixture model to classify MNIST images, and I'm running into pathological cases which screw up my calculations.

The pdf of a multidimensional (let's say N dimensions) Bernoulli distribution is as such:
$P(x|\mu) = \prod\limits_{i=0}^{N}\mu_{i}^{x_i}(1 - \mu_{i})^{(1 - x_i)}$

The pdf of a mixture of thoses being a weighted sum of them.

Dealing with small probabilities, I naturally turned to log probabilities, and transformed the equation as such:

$log(P(x|\mu) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{N}log(\mu_{i}^{x_i}) + log((1 - \mu_{i})^{(1 - x_i)})$

My problem is, what happens when $\mu_i$ becomes either 0 or 1 during training? I end up with $log(0^1)$, which yields -Inf and ruins my classification.

Are those case pathological, or is there a way to represent them in a sane way?

I thought of considering those cases a pathological, because they typically represent corners of the image on which no pixel ever wanders, and running a PCA to reduce dimensionality, but I'm not sure how I can proceed from there: I can understand reducing my dataset to D' dimensions, and so having my centers of D' dimensions, but how can I use them with an image from my validation set, which is still D dimensions? I feel using the coefficients from my training set will introduce bias.

Thanks for your help, and cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I too have recently programmed Bernoulli naive Bayes from scratch for MNIST classification. I decided to eliminate all unchanging pixels from computations. For the MNIST images, many pixels around the outside are black and always black. If a pixel is always the same across images, it obviously contains no useful information for classification. Therefore nothing is lost by ignoring it. BTW this problem also arises for example if one is implementing Gaussian naive Bayes--the density when SD=0 is Inf. I use the general principle of eliminating unchanging pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Laplace smoothing to avoid probabilities to be zero.

Laplace smoothing is: 
`if (m/N == 0)` then
   `(m+1)/(N+#classes)`;

Comment: Laplace smoothing is actually $\frac{x_{i} + \alpha}{N + \alpha d}$, where $x_{i}$ is the count of category $i$, $N$ is the total sample size, $d$ is the number of classes, and $\alpha > 0$ is a 'smoothing' parameter that controls how closely the smoothed distribution approaches the uniform distribution $\frac{1}{d}$. The smoothing is applied to all categories, not just those with $x_{i} = 0$, as if you did that then you'd no longer have a distribution summing to $1$ over all categories. Perhaps you can expand your answer to reflect this, and suggest why you think $\alpha = 1$ is a good value.